# Saving Excel file in ASP.NET MVC 5.1 caused COMException -> it tries to save it in my documents instead in project resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, azure, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to create excel file on server side then send it to the client(enable download):

```
  public ActionResult ExportToExcel() {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();    
            xlApp.Visible = true;

            Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];


            // Select the Excel cells, in the range c1 to c7 in the worksheet.
            Range aRange = ws.get_Range("C1", "C7");

            // Fill the cells in the C1 to C7 range of the worksheet with the number 6.
            Object[] args = new Object[1];
            args[0] = 6;
            aRange.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, aRange, args);

            // Change the cells in the C1 to C7 range of the worksheet to the number 8.
            aRange.Value2 = 8;


            wb.SaveAs(@"~/Content/export.xlsx");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

It causes: `InteropServices.COMException`:

> "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\s8359_000\Documents\~\Content\03AB3A00'. There are
>   several possible reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not
>   exist.\n• The file is being used by another program.\n• The workbook
>   you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook."

**The issue:** Basically I want to save inside project(which will be in Azure) or just send it to the client(user) without saving. I used samples from MSDN, but it keeps saving it in my filesystem.

EDIT:

Dennis' solution worked, but the additional element has been added to the output:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel() {
            var datasource = new List<string> { "TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3" }; // Your Data Source

            if (datasource != null) {
                var gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = datasource;
                gv.DataBind();

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
               "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "FileName.xls"));
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
                        gv.RenderControl(htw);
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                    }
                }

                return new EmptyResult();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Look at the error carefully. That file location doesn't look right at all.

Comment: @failedprogramming it worked when I used exacly the same syntax in Razor view when loading images. How other way get to the root of the project?

Comment: You REALLY shouldn't be using Excel interop in a web project anyway.

Comment: @DavidG I've done few hours research there is no out of the box example to create EXCEL file in ASP.NET MVC and download it. I tried few, they usually don't say if it is going to work in ASP .NET and don't tell about references.

Comment: @DavidG is correct. You will likely have a problem when more than 1 person tries to do this process at the same time.

Comment: @failedprogramming I am sure you are right, the issue is I don't know how to create the excel file in ASP.NET MVC. I went trhough SO questions.

Comment: @Yoda I am quite sure that Workbook.SaveAs() needs to have a full path. You can probably use Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/export.xlsx") to resolve the full path.

Comment: @Yoda Would csv be an acceptable replacement? Otherwise you might need to look at OpenXML.

Comment: @failedprogramming I am checking it. What did you mean saying "2 ppl"?  AHHH 2 people. Won't happen. Thanks. It is closed application, and only one user can do it, but I know that this code might need replacement in far future.

Comment: @DavidG Executing this code causes automatic openning EXCEL file in my computer should I somehow prevent it happenning? It will be on the AZURE side so I don't think it is a good thing.

Comment: This almost certainly won't work on Azure

Comment: https://epplus.codeplex.com/ works great for generating Excel files.  Doesn't require any excel components be installed on your server, and is alot faster than COM interop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can download your data into an excel at client side. Create a GridView at runtime and bind your datasource to the gridview. You will have to reference `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` and other namespaces as appropriate.

```
 public ActionResult ExcelDownload()
 {
      var datasource =  GetDataSource (); // Your Data Source

      if (datasource != null)
      {
         var gv = new GridView();
         gv.DataSource = datasource;
         gv.DataBind();

         HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "FileName.xls"));
         HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
         HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

         using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
         {
             using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
             {
                 gv.RenderControl(htw);
                 HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                 HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                 HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
             }
         }

         return new EmptyResult();
      }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }
```

And you can call the `ExcelDownload` ActionResult method through a `@Html.ActionLink`

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Excel Download", "ExcelDownload",
    null, new { @title = "Click to download as an Excel report" })
```

Or an alternate would be to consider tools like [EppPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: In `HttpContext` I have 2 things starting with `Current` one is: `HttpContext.CurrentHandler` and `HttpContext.CurrentNotification`. Also what type of object `GetDataSource()` should return?

Comment: Your `GetDataSource()` can return any IEnumerable object (whatever you're tring to export to Excel). I have been using this in my MVC application and it works well.

Comment: Thank you. I had to add `System.Web.` before `HttpContext` but it was resolving `HttpContext` just didn't contain `Current` inside.

Comment: If it is `IEnumerable` it is probalby going into one row is there any way to inser sth inside cell for instance `B4`?

Comment: You'll have to reference `using System.Web;using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`. As for as the IEnumerable you can send any collection of rows and columns. `var datasource` can reference to any list of custom collection. So obviously you would want to export the same data what you show up on the view page right? If yes, then reference the same data.

Comment: You helped my greatly, could you please have a glance at EDIT in Original Post? I got additional item added to the output and elements are added vertically.

Comment: The 'Item' is the header name (ie. the column name you have given for the data source). You can hide the header for the gridview if you don't want to. It seems like you have 3 rows and a single column defined in your sample data which are shown as vertically. If each row is having additional columns then define in the data source which will be displayed horizontally.